# Matlab Colon Operator equivalent in Vpython

Tags: python, matlab, vpython

After spending the last few months learning about MATLAB, it seems I need to switch to vpython! MATLAB's colon operator comes in handy often and I haven't found an equivalent in vpython.

For reference, in MATLAB:

-3:3 = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]

Is there any easy way to do the same thing in vPython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know vpython, but after perusing its [tutorial](http://vpython.org/contents/docs/visual/VPython_Intro.pdf), I would guess it is the [same as in Python](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range):

```
range(-3,4)
# [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use numpy, you can use numpy.r_ :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.r_[-3:4]
array([-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3])
>>> np.r_[-3:4, -5:7]
array([-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,
        5,  6])
```